# Meteor Performance Issue

Tags: node.js, meteor

So I have a Meteor application that is working fine on my local machine, but when I deploy to production is has terrible delays resulting in terrible performance.

Currently it talks to two services - a data processing service and mongodb. As well as the client of course.

I'm using Meteor 7.1.2, so I know it's using capped collections and op-log tailing.

I've optimized my code in every way possible but its still slow in the following ways:

1. Slow to load
2. Intermittent (bad) delays when sending requests to the data processing server.

Any suggestions would be VERY appreciated , as i've just about had it with Meteor and thinking about switching to bare-bones express and building on that.

Thanks!

Comment: "Slow to load. Intermittent (bad) delays when sending requests to the data processing server." In all likeliness, this has nothing to do with Meteor, but rather your code. *Post some code* that has issues. A blanket question like this is rather useless.

Comment: "Just about had it with Meteor" - you should try bare-bones express and see how quickly you get fed up with that!

Answer (score 4):

Can you please try to use [Kadira](https://kadira.io/)?

It will show you what's really happening.

> Disclaimer: I maintain Kadira.